# After upgrading to Android Developer Tools version 22, compiling fails

Tags: android, adt

Today, I upgraded ADT to version 22. After that, my projet wouldn't compile resources at all. My "gen" folder was empty and as such all my java files that require "R" wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After a few non-full time hours, I restarted the "Android SDK Manager" and this time, I noticed these:
 - "Android SDK Platform Tools" (upgrade)
 - "Android SDK built-tools" (new)

After installing those, I was finally able to fully compile my project.

Comment: i'm having problems with it. it seems the tool called "aapt.exe" doesn't exist anymore, which other tools depend on (like maven). What can I do?

Comment: I cannot find "aapt" (Mac/Linux version of the same program" under my android-sdk-mac_86" folder.  That said, my project still compiles via the command line.

I might venture a guess, Alex. What is did you run "android update project" to update your build files?

Comment: aapt is now located in $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/17.0.0

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact same thing that happened to me! Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

ADT22 use Android Private Libraries show project/libs'jar, add Exported feature, if you wannt reference library projects' private libraries, you must check the Exported

https://plus.google.com/photos/117122118961369445953/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162?authkey=CL3Frb-S_qj-fQ

Comment: I first installed "Android SDK built-tools" as @GenesisST explains in his answer. Then in "Order and Export" I checked "Android Private Libraries" as shown in your link and now everything works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using some libraries or/and dependencies with other projects, you may also experience errors at execution time. In my case I had problems with Sherlock *"Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr"* and with some other jar file I am using *"VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature"* In that case, you must go to project properties, Java Build Path section, and remove Android Dependencies and Android Private Libraries, both in the main project and also in the dependent projects like for example Sherlock. After that you perform Clean on all projects. Everything should be restored. That worked for me, after a hard battle!

Comment: Thanks. Deleting both dependencies and private libs then clean did the job.