# Can't update Eclipse ADT to 22

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I wanted to export my projects to Android Studio but Eclipse is not getting updated...

So far I've [added a s in http to the url of the update source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-0latest-version-from-21-1-0), moved [ADT outside Program Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544071/an-error-occurred-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed-access-is-denied), remove the "Only read" flag on all the files, [updated the sdk and all the new components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578147/after-upgrading-to-android-developer-tools-version-22-compiling-fails), but when I look for updates Eclipse doesn't find anything and if I install "Android Developer Tools" through "Install new software", this long error log pops up.

Any idea or you recommend to just download ADT again?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.0.200.v20120530-1204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.5.301.v20121210-210948
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.8.1.v201302041200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.3.500.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.0.400.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui,3.3.300.v20120522-1651
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.0.600.v20130116-050536
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.0.200.v20130116-050536
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.8.3.v20130121-145325
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.5.0.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.7.101.v20120913-153601
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.6.100.v20120530-1425
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.8.2.v20130121-200410
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.7.100.v20120523-1543
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core,3.7.100.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime,3.4.301.v20120914-131016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime,1.1.200.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.6.101.v20130111-183046
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.8.2.v20130107-165834
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.200.v201203141800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.201.v201208292200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.201.v201301092200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.201.v201208241600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets,1.2.200.v201204260225
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.0.v201203071939
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.core,1.1.600.v201205171933
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui,1.0.700.v201203081826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache,1.0.600.v201203071939
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.702.v201301241617
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.102.v201301162301
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas,1.0.501.v201301091615
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.402.v201212031633
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.400.v201204260100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.702.v201301101836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.302.v201301172222
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core,1.1.700.v201204102147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.500.v201203081826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit,4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit4,4.8.1.v20120523-1257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,1.0.1.v20130111-135246
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.jdt_root,3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.4.2.v201212051536-7B7EFMVF7RZHOkJkNwS4TV
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.4.2.v201212051536-7C7AFeFEdhOaweLhCnQfylKlOxT5UW
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.4.2.v201211061806-7C7OFm9F7RZHQVHiOz-P0Up
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX
```

Comment: yes you need to again download ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html this bundle contains SDK and Eclipse

Comment: That really shouldn't be necessary, the whole point of the repository system is to provide updates.
Maybe a server has fallen over somewhere.

Comment: See the solution posted by CRUSADER. The location is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961. It worked for me.

Comment: The answer by laalto worked for me- the update site needs to be https not http

Comment: I've tried [laalto's suggestion][1], and worked for me!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16589558/2684718

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I updated my tools to r22 using SDK Manager and ADT plugin using Eclipse's "Check for Updates". For some reason I still had:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above

I resolved this by reinstalling Eclipse ADT plugin using Eclipse's "Install New Software" feature and using `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` as the repo URL.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I guess "https" made the difference. Deses, you might want to change it to https and try once.

Comment: A coworker today had the same errors as @Deses in the question, and after restarting Eclipse he was greeted with the error message in this answer. Solution was the same.

Comment: This is the answer. Three times I had this problem, three times this was the solution

Answer (score 14):

You can direct Download [ADT22.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.0.zip)

Comment: OK, I tried to install that adding the archive as source and installing the developer tools, and a similar error happens...It seems that I just can't update it. :/

Comment: I give it another shot (I still have the old installation folder) and when I uninstall it, another long error log pops. It's just broken. :(

Answer (score 7):

Well, I just got tired of fiddling with eclipse, so I completely erased it and reinstalled it with the pluings needed and end of story, I'm pretty sick of Eclipse breaking on me every time I have to update it.

So the easiest and quickest way is reinstall. Sometimes, trying to fix something is futile.

Comment: Same here, fully erasing and reinstalling is the only thing that worked. Yes it's really getting ridiculous how often this happens.

Comment: *Bro hug*
Hopefully when Android Studio gets better and gets out of alpha will be a solid alternative to Eclipse, right now I can't use it. (Also, I need tutorials, because I don't know how to do much of the stuff)

Answer (score 5):

I also followed steps 1,2,3,4... but as stated above,  this didn't work for me until I unchecked "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" in the Install dialog when I did "Install new software".

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully the issue is long resolved.
I faced similar issues while updating my ADT 21 to 22 with Ubuntu 12.10

I just launched ADT from command line as a ***SUPERUSER***  and then tried the same:
Help > Install New Software > ADT Update site 
and voila, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to help, install new software and select from the dropdown Android Developers Tools it also has the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ link next to it. After that Select the updates that will appear below.

Then CLick Next, Choose Accept and Finish.
This will download the updates.

OR 
Alternatively add the ADT again as you did initially by giving the name, and specifying the url as https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, this didn't work for me until  I unchecked "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" in the Install dialog when I did "Install new software".

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software".
See: [Can not install Android ADT 21.1 on eclipse Juno (Windows 7) after upadate to SDK 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866656/can-not-install-android-adt-21-1-on-eclipse-juno-windows-7-after-upadate-to-sd)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and the steps below worked for me:
1. Exit eclipse
2. Run eclipse as an administrator
3. Go to help, install new software
4. Select from the drop-down list (or directly paste this link): 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ 
5. Click next and follow the other instructions.

This will download the updates. Now, restart the adt.

Answer (score -2):

i think the problem with eclipse. previously ur downloaded bundle of android sdk manager. it it's ture means, plz u can download superate ecplise and install and use existing sdk for that. ur prob ll solve