# Eclipse wizard to create new Android Activity doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my first question, I hope to make it right. I have a problem with Eclipse and Android. I'm using the last build of the Android ADT bundle, **adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030**, and when I try to use the procedure *new --> other --> Android Activity* to an existing project, it doesn't do nothing and I see on the error log tab that give me two errors:

First Error

```
 Expression manifestOut is undefined on line 9, column 39 in recipe.xml.ftl.
    The problematic instruction:
    ----------
    ==> ${escapeXmlAttribute(manifestOut)} [on line 9, column 18 in recipe.xml.ftl]
    ----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression manifestOut is undefined on line 9, column 39 in recipe.xml.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.ListLiteral.getValueList(ListLiteral.java:95)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.execute(TemplateHandler.java:546)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$1(TemplateHandler.java:537)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$1.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:463)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.processVariables(TemplateHandler.java:430)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.render(TemplateHandler.java:295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewTemplateWizardState.computeChanges(NewTemplateWizardState.java:164)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplatePreviewPage.setVisible(TemplatePreviewPage.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Second Error

```
pression manifestDir is undefined on line 4, column 39 in globals.xml.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${manifestDir} [on line 4, column 37 in globals.xml.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression manifestDir is undefined on line 4, column 39 in globals.xml.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.processVariables(TemplateHandler.java:423)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$0(TemplateHandler.java:409)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$1.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:458)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.processVariables(TemplateHandler.java:430)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.render(TemplateHandler.java:295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewTemplateWizardState.computeChanges(NewTemplateWizardState.java:164)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplatePreviewPage.setVisible(TemplatePreviewPage.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

How can I solve this?
The Session Data showed in the windows error is this:

**

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
```

**

**EDIT:**
I have found that even when I try to create a new Android Project doesn't create the first **MainActivity** that usually it should create

Comment: The wizard should do all this things, even refactoring the Android Manifest to add the new activity, but it doesn't modify nothing in my project and give me these two errors

Comment: the problem seems to be in this `freemarker.core` package and not eclipse itself

Comment: For now I resolved using Eclipse Kepler+ ADT plugin and not using the bundle. Maybe there's a problem with this new release

Comment: @MatteoM : i am getting same problem after last sdk update. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @MatteoM: Great job on your first question!

Comment: @Ajay I decided to use a normal Eclipse version with just the Android SDK not in bundle and the ADT plug in. It works

Comment: @MatteoM : it was solved by just updating ADT to latest version. :)

Comment: @Ajay Happy to know it :) but for now I stay with my actual organization :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved similar problem doing this:

"Help" -> "Install new software", then put url https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ for getting updates, it will reinstall new versions.

Comment: Note that the URL must start with "https".  It doesn't work (!) with "http:".  See the first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22

Comment: I had the same problem with eclipse android. That solved my problem as well. thanks.

Comment: I tried this, and while it looks like it works for most people it is not fixing the issue for me. I did it once and now, as expected, it says I have everything installed. But I still cannot create activities

Comment: Same here. It installs, but still no create activity. Any other suggestions? @KorayGüclü You can do it the old fashioned way: 1) add activity entry to androidmanifest.xml and create the class, and the layout and the menu all by hand, or copy from an existing working activity. That's all the wizard really does anyway. It's just nicer if the wizard works.

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with the last update. I've find another way to solve it. In the sdk folder I've deleted the "tools" folder, download de sdk from the web http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and copy the "tools" folder from this zip to the sdk location in my computer. That have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note,
From the Android SDK Manager, ensure that you have installed "Android Support Repository" & "Android Support Library".

I had installed only the later and I was having the same issue as you.
When I installed the first one too, then I was able to see "MainActivity" created as expected.

Comment: I read that the "Android Support Repository" is it necessary instead of "Android Support Library" if you are using Android Studio as IDE to develop.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same problem with mine recently. I managed to the problem. Whatever the update was to the android bundle messed up the system. To solve my problem, you have to delete the extracted files from the adt bundle. Once it's deleted then re-extract the adt zip files again in your desired location. Once you have it, load the sdk manager and install all the programs that you want, but don't update any of the files that say they're available for updates. Once you have everything else, your program should operate just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall ADT and read https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82393#makechanges

Download http://tools.android.com/download/adt-issue-82393-v2.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Then -> Help -> Install New -> Add -> Archive and select it.

Fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last month. The "Install new software" procedure didn't work for me, it found that I was up to date. I just updated "Android SDK Tools" (24.0.2) today using the "Android SDK Manager" and it works fine again.