# Eclipse doesn't create Main Activity and layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can't start new projects anymore. This is what I do...

- Start Eclipse.
- New Android Application

  - min **API 8**
  - target **API 18**
  - compile **API 19**
  - create activity : checked
  - activity name : `MainActivity`
  - layout name : `activity_main`
  - finish

When I open the project (it doesn't even open `MainActivity.java` as it should be) :
- *src* folder is empty
- *res/layout* folder is empty

But *AndroidManifest.xml* exists. It was working perfectly before and I was able to create projects then it just suddenly broke.

I'm using APIs 18 and 19 all installed and up to date.

Comment: did u try to restart the eclipse and kill adb and clean build it ..

Comment: yup.  
1. File -> Restart  
2. Close. Open.  
3. Restart PC.  
only src and res/layout folder is empty. gen folder still has generated files in it.

Comment: kill adb..and then restart your ecliipse...

Comment: I think ur android plugin of eclipse goes wrong .. uninstall that and install it again.

Comment: does that mean I have to redownload eclipse? or just a part of it? (I'm quite new to programming.)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218581/eclipse-wizard-to-create-new-android-activity-doesnt-work

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday after updating the latest packages on the Android SDK Manager.

Fixed it by updating the Eclipse plugin: `Run Eclipse` > `Help` > `Install new software` > `Paste the URL` **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/** then press `Enter`. After updating the plugin, I created a test project with the main activity and menu was created by default as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem before.

Using this Eclipse Update http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ did not work for me.
I notice this problem when I download the latest updated SDK

[image]

Luckily the solution to my problem is very easy.
[image]

By Selecting Empty Project instead of Blank Activity makes it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with opening the layout folder. I needed a xml file with the contents as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

So,this is what I did.I tried updating eclipse but, the problem persisted. So,I just created a new xml file by right-clicking the layout folder.After creating the file,I just copy-pasted the aforementioned content.Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. It suddenly stopped creating `MainActivity.java` and layout. I could fix it by updating Eclipse:
**Help -> Check for updates -> Select all**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problema also. I fixed the problem follow the Werner recomendation. Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> Pasted URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ pressed Enter, but It's important check it out and remove before any copy of the plugin installed in available Software Sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem also. I fixed the problem follow the Werner recomendation. Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> Pasted URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ 
It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue on Mac 10.9.1. For what appears to be no reason, when creating a new android project, the "src" directory is empty, and there's no activity_main.xml. I tried Werner's fix, but the URL had issues trying to download the files. 
Deleted Eclipse, and re-installed. 
This appears to have fixed the issue.

Actually - still having this issue, even after re-installing Eclipse...

Comment: I did the same thing - completely reinstalled the whole SDK and I still have this issue.