# Eclipse not generate activity xml layout files?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using the android developer bundle and every time I start a new application the layout directory in the res folder is empty. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Eclipse plugin:

```
Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

I had the same problem, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219392/eclipse-doesnt-create-main-activity-and-layout) helped. Take a look as well to 
*user3347036*'s answer regarding XML files. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its a known Bug.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

Issue 66647:    Eclipse bundles with Android SDK download, doesn't create Main Activity when trying to create a new Android Application (after updating the Android Support Library).

Solve the Issue by installing updates as:

```
click "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the latest packages on the Android SDK Manager. 
Update Eclipse plugin:
 Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> Pasted URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
 pressed Enter.

Refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219392/eclipse-doesnt-create-main-activity-and-layout)