# Eclipse wont create new Android Activity source or layout. Tried updates and sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I create new android project I select blank activity with fragment (tried empty activity and blank activity as well) and go through the naming process for layout name but when project is created, there's no .java source file and no layout folder or xml contents.

I've tried the following but still nothing: 
[ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)
[Eclipse doesn't create Main Activity and layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219392/eclipse-doesnt-create-main-activity-and-layout)

Go to "Help Menu Bar" -> "Install New software" and install (this will update it) url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

It says all installs have been done for adt plugin, all installs done for sdk manager, no updates found under help - check for updates.

I uninstalled eclipse, got newest version but no luck. I have newest adt plugin version 23.0 as well. I tried restarting eclipse and going to task manager and stopping adb.exe process and restarting eclipse but nothing. I tried changing my work space to another location but still nothing. Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yersteday.
I tried many things, installing a clean Eclipse (latest version) with the newest ADT, using the bundle and updating, nothing worked.
When I went on the android IRC I got the following answer :
Use Android Studio.

ADT 23 seems to be broken at the moment, sadly.

Comment: I'm trying android studio now. not bad, but I a little tricky setup. anyone now how the testsource works?

Comment: I believe you are refering to unit testing?
If so check this : http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/