# Eclipse does not generate New Activity after I download the latest SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I start my first Eclipse Project but I cannot create any Activity, I already Restart my IDE and Even restarting my Computer does not help.

What I did when creating a Project:
 File - > New Android Project - > Fill-up Information (min:API-8,Target and Build:Android 4.XL prev)  next ---> next ---> Blank Activity ---> Fill-up Again -- > Finish

But no activity is in the SRC folder, I need to know whats wrong with my IDE or related to my problem.

I also done Updating using this CDN http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  but it wont work.

Comment: Yes Sir and It does not help me.

Comment: Have you updated the ADT?

Comment: Yes Sir I did the Update, AT first I got Connection Error cause by my internet after the next try It is successfully installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue as you do and I have a working solution which is I already posted here

[Eclipse doesn't create Main Activity and layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219392/eclipse-doesnt-create-main-activity-and-layout/27762184#27762184)

Using this Eclipse Update http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ did not work for me. I notice this problem when I download the latest updated SDK
[image]

Luckily the solution to my problem is very easy. 
[image]

By Selecting Empty Project instead of Blank Activity makes it working.

Comment: It also bother me a lot after Updating SDK but however I got it working after I used Empty Activity.