# Eclipse wizard no longer creates activities in Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse

The exact problem described in [this nine-month-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218581/eclipse-wizard-to-create-new-android-activity-doesnt-work) suddenly (and apparently spontaneously) manifested for me today.  It worked as recently as a few days ago.  None of the answers on that older question solved the problem.  In addition, I've tried updating all my Eclipse plugins to the latest versions, and tried creating a project in a clean new workspace.  No dice

Has this happened to you recently?  What is the solution?

(On a side note, can anyone explain why the most popular program used by programmers to write programs is such a complete piece of garbage?  Grrr...)

**Edit:** After attempting to fix this via all the suggested methods, I have now also lost the ability to do Team > Revert... on any file or project.  Yay!  Looks like I'll be getting familiar with Android Studio this weekend.

Comment: The solution probably is to create the activities manually, or to move to Android Studio. Note that Google is no longer supporting Eclipse, so until the Eclipse Andmore initiative gets rolling in earnest, Eclipse users are left out in the cold.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't help feeling that "not supporting" should be read as "deliberately breaking."  But it's hard to point fingers at Google, since Eclipse breaks itself so frequently anyway. *sigh*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse wizard to create new Android Activity doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218581/eclipse-wizard-to-create-new-android-activity-doesnt-work)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Honestly, from my experience, Android Studio is much better anyway. It has been a great experience all around. I'd consider switching if I were you.

Comment: @JonAdams It's not clear that it's a duplicate because although the symptoms are identical, none of the previously accepted solutions work, so the underlying issue may be different.  If someone adds a new answer to the older question, then this one may become a duplicate.

Comment: @AlexK I've been considering it for a long time.  This may be the last nail in Eclipse's coffin.

Comment: It once happened to me: I updated the SDK components, but then forgot to do `Help/Check for updates`. Which **solved the issue**.

Comment: @DerGolem I tried that.  It does not fix the problem.