# This Android SDk requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above Please update ADT to the latest version.

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

My codes won't run on the emulator and I get the Error: This Android SDk requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above . Current version is 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705. Please update ADT to the latest version. I checked for updates but cannot find any. Please help

Comment: Possible almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22?