# Can't configure Android SDK in ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to setup Android SDK on Eclipse ADT but I can't since I'm getting a error saying that Android SDK is outdated when is not. Since one image is better than millions of words take a look at images below:

SDK Manager: showing Android latest SDK installed

[image]

Eclipse ADT: finding for the SDK path and notice how ADT doesn't allow me to apply them

[image]
[image]

What is wrong here? Why ADT doesn't find any on that folder?

**Swtich from ADT to Android Development Studio**

As suggested from one member here I switched from ADT to ADS but I can't open the IDE since I got this error all the time:

> Error launching Android Studio The environment variable JAVA_HOME
>   (with the value of c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib) does not point to
>   a valid JVM installation.

In terminal I run the command `java -version` and I get this as output:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

What is the right path to configure the JVM? Do I miss to install anything else?

Comment: I had this problem once and the reason was that the Android SDK Manager actually didn't store the downloaded data in the folder which the Eclipse config assumes to be the Android SDK folder. In my case I had duplicate Android SDK folder, one of which contained up to date data, whereas the other was more or less empty. Check your filesystem against your configurations. If there's really only one SDK folder I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. :(

Comment: Is there an equivalent windows command to the *nix `which` command? If I were on OS X or *nix, the first thing I would do is run `which java` -> That will tell you the location of the Java installed on your actual path. Based on a quick search, maybe you should try `where java` in the windows terminal. What does that say?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have a better time if you just skip Eclipse and go strait to Android Studio.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Already downloading but I'll also try @mabvt way, thanks both

Comment: can you take a look to my latest edit? I can't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update ADT plugin. Set repo URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and click "Install New Software" . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589558/192373.