# Android SDK ADT mismatch but cannot find update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Here is the error message I am getting when I start eclipse after updating through Android SDK Manager.

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or
>   above.
>
> Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031
>
> Please update ADT to the latest version

The problem is when I click update or go to help to find latest update, there is no update available. So okay, I did some research and found this link [Can't update Eclipse ADT to 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22). So then I tried to install the ADT anew. Now I am getting the following issue:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
>   Software currently installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android
>   3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group
>   3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       ADT XML Overlay 23.0.6.1720515 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.6.1720515)
>       ADT XML Overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay
>   22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
>       To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.6.1720515]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
>       To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group
>   3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0

Comment: ADT is a mess now, switch to Android Studio ASAP.

Comment: I want to switch to android studio but mine is a "App Engine connected android project" with a number of jars such joda-time, etc. I don't know how long it would take and how much damage I would cause before successfully transitioning.

Answer (score 2):

Help-->Install New Software-->What is already installed?

Then, Select "Android DDMS, Andoid Devlopment Tools,Android Hierarcy Viewer, Android native Development Tools, Android Traceview, Tracer for OpenGL ES" and click Uninstall.

After all this step, try Add link (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and name is ADT Plugin. This link will get the latest ADT Plugin. In this way you reinstall the ADT.