# Google Play Services not found after ADT Update

Tags: android, adt

I was trying to get an environment setup today and after getting the SDK, ADT, Eclipse etc set up I imported the project to the new work space. After install developer tools version 22.0 the google play services lib in the project "can't be resolved". None of the map classes can be resolved - Marker, Camera Position, LatLng, Google Map etc.

In a different environment I was running version 21.1 of the Developer Tools. The project would run fine there until I updated the Developer Tools.

I was curious if anyone else has experienced this and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Dup of: [After upgrading to Android Developer Tools version 22, compiling fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578147/after-upgrading-to-android-developer-tools-version-22-compiling-fails)

Check this post:
https://plus.google.com/photos/117122118961369445953/albums/5878509263473846433/5878509268379848162

Please also check on SDK Manager if you have the new "Android SDK Build-tools" installed!

What I have done:

- Eclipse -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export = checked "Android Private Library" and "Android Dependencies"
- SDK Manager = SDK Build-tools installed
- SDK Manager = Android Plataform-tools v17 installed

Comment: I added the private libraries and it's still telling me none of the google API's objects can be found. It's not the NoClassDefFoundError referenced in the Google Plus post, it's that the Google API classes cannot be resolved. Thoughts.?

Comment: I updated my answer with one more thing to check! Please try that too!

Comment: Yup, I've got everything installed from the SDK Manager and I checked the Private Library on Order and Export. 

I have three libraries I'm importing - the jfeinstein sliding menu, a SAX-RSS-Reader and the google-play-services_lib. The Menu and SaxREader work just fine but none of the google map classes can be resolved to a type. I've tried it by building a new project etc and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please check if the "google-play-services_lib" is properly set as an Android Library Project and if you are properly referencing it as a library project.

Comment: Yup. Both of those seem to be working correctly. The project was building fine Friday morning and then I updated the ADT/SDK stuff and it broke.

Comment: Ok well, I went through and took out the imports I had for the GoogleMaps stuff and did a "fix project setup" in eclipse. It brought in google-play-services_lib jar and things seemed to be fixed.