# Android Studio doesn't work on Windows 8

Tags: android, configuration, android-studio

I've setup Android Studio in Windows 7 and it's work fine for me. But the same installation I try with Windows 8 seems to not be working. For some reason the installer can't find the Java SDK, even when JAVA_HOME is set to its location.

Has anybody configured Android Studio in Windows 8? Is there any additional special configuration required to work on Windows 8 like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16578147/893605)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add environment variable ANDROID_STUDIO_SDK with the path to the jdk in the system (right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced).

Comment: I followed all the basic steps which required on Windows 7, and also added ANDROID_STUDIO_SDK and JDK_HOME as well as JAVA_HOME in Environment variables but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What about version of your system and java? x86 or x64? I had a problem that I had Win8 x64 installed, but Java x86. Reinstalling a proper version solved this problem.

Comment: JAVA 7 Update 21 and Win8 x64

Comment: All I needed to do was set JDK_HOME as per this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582107/android-studio-doesnt-start ), mine is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21